# Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair documentation

Tags: discussion, feature-request

**Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair documentation**

Just like the [Stackoverflow Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation), it would be wonderful to have a documentation for Maintenance & Repair of different types of vehicles. I know there are so many vehicles out there and the documentation will be endless process. This is just a suggestion, please write your opinion on this matter.

Comment: This isn't a bad idea at all. I'm just wondering how it would flesh out. We could bring a lot of knowledge here to Mech with this.

Comment: Yes, It would be a great reference tool for the mechanics and DIY-enthusiasts.

Comment: I'd love to see/contribute to something like this!  A sort of open-source, community-editable Haynes manual.

Answer (score 8):

This has been asked on several other sites.  The official answer seems to be from this post on the main meta site:
[Allow Documentation in other Stack Exchange communities](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/281689/236563)

As of last November, there are no plans by the SE team to roll the feature out elsewhere.
Yet!

If it keeps being requested, it will probably come eventually.

Comment: Within months, the Stackoverflow Documentation has filled up with lots of quality information on different languages and still in Beta stage. Now, it is almost a great reference tool that every programmer can rely on. I just want the same for the Mechanics.